# recursive iteration through python dictionary from mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, recursion, pymongo

This is the document I currently have in MongoDB.

```
{
"name":"food",
"core":{
    "group":{
         "carbs":{
            "abbreviation": "Cs"
            "USA":{
                "breakfast":"potatoes",
                "dinner":"pasta"
            },
            "europe":{
                "breakfast":"something",
                "dinner":"something big"
            }
        },
         "abbreviation": "Ds"
         "dessert":{
             "USA":{
                 "breakfast":"potatoes and eggs",
                 "dinner":"pasta"
        },
         "europe":{
                 "breakfast":"something small",
                 "dinner":"hello"
        }
    },
        "abbreviation": "Vs"
        "veggies":{
                        "USA":{
                                "breakfast":"broccoli",
                                "dinner":"salad"
                        },
                        "europe":{
                                "breakfast":"cheese",
                                "dinner":"asparagus"
                        }
                 }  
            }
      }
 }
```

I extract the data from mongo with the following lines of code.

```
data = collection.foodie.find({"name":"food"}, {"name":False, '_id':False})
def recursee(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            print recursee(d)
        else:
            print "{0} : {1}".format(k,v)
```

However, when i run the recursee function, it fails to print group : carbs, group : dessert, or group : veggies.  Instead i get the below output.

```
breakfast : something big
dinner : something
None
abbreviation : Cs
breakfast : potatoes
dinner : pasta
None
None
breakfast : something small
dinner : hello
None
abbreviation : Ds
breakfast : potatoes and eggs
dinner : pasta
None
None
breakfast : cheese
dinner : asparagus
None
abbreviation : Vs
breakfast : broccoli
dinner : salad
```

Am i skipping something in my recursion that is bypassing printing the group and corresponding value?

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions):

> The [`return`](https://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) statement returns with a value from a function. `return` without an expression argument returns `None`. Falling off the end of a function also returns `None`.

Because your `recursee` has no `return` statement, i.e. it implicitly returns `None`, so next statement

```
print recursee(d)
```

executes `recursee` with `d` object as an argument and prints function output (which is `None`)

Try

```
def recursee(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print "{0} :".format(k)
            recursee(v)
        else:
            print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)
```